# I18n configuration under config/application.rb is ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization, rails-i18n

I am trying to setup Internationalization in my app. 
I have setup `config/application.rb` as follows:

```
  class Application < Rails::Application

    I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
    I18n.enforce_available_locales = false

    I18n.available_locales = [:en, :fr]

    I18n.default_locale = :fr
  end
```

In my `application_controller.rb` I am trying to setup the locale based on a subdomain:

```
  before_action :set_locale

  def set_locale
    puts(I18n.default_locale)
    I18n.locale = extract_locale_from_subdomain || I18n.default_locale
  end

  def extract_locale_from_subdomain
    parsed_locale = request.subdomains.first
    I18n.available_locales.map(&:to_s).include?(parsed_locale) ? parsed_locale : nil
    puts(parsed_locale)
  end
```

The first `puts` prints `en` and the second one correctly prints the subdomain, eg `gr`, `fr` or whatever I set.

It seems that my configuration in `config/application.rb` is ignored.

I have added `127.0.0.1 fr.app.local` into my `etc/hosts` so I can test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the `config` object in your `config/application.rb` file.

`I18n.default_locale = :fr` won't give you what you want. You need to do `config.i18n.default_locale = :fr`

Try this:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
  config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = false
  config.i18n.available_locales = [:en, :fr]
  config.i18n.default_locale = :fr
end
```

You can learn more about configuring Rails components [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It doesn't work. Nothing changed.

Comment: I forgot that `i18n` needs to be lowercase in the config file.  So, `config.i18n.default_locale` instead of `config.I18n.default_locale`.  I edited the answer.  Can you try again?

Comment: Tried, also no positive results.

Comment: Is it possible `I18n.default_locale` is being changed in another file?  Perhaps in `config/initializers/locale.rb` if that file exists.  A project wide search for `default_locale` might be helpful.

Comment: Nop, there is no `locale.rb` file and `default_locale` is not modified in the production/test/development files.

Comment: There are only 3 usages of `default_locale` after running the project wide search, the ones I mention in my question.

Comment: Restarting the server including your proposed changed worked. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, glad to hear!  In the context of configuration changes: when in doubt, restart the Rails server.